# Maximum distance after 99 steps with 90 degree turns after each

Tags: geometry

> John takes 300 steps to walk from point A to point B in a flat field. Each step
>   is of length $1/\sqrt{2}$ meters, and he makes a $90^\circ$ turn after every step except after the last one. He makes 99 left turns and 200 right turns in total. He stops at
>   point B. What is the maximum possible distance from A to B?

Someone please help me. I first tried to make isoceles triangles which gave me a hypotenuse of 1 and connecting them together I got 150 triangles so I thought that the answer was 150m but the memo says that is incorrect? Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be 100m. Any additional right turns just take you back to your starting point. Therefore you go 100m by going right left right left... and with the 100 right turns remaining you simply go in circles.